# Makefile process list of files in a file

Tags: list, file, makefile

I have a file containing a list of files to process, one per line. They do not have a filename pattern: they could have one of many extensions.

Can I get make to read the filenames from the file? I tried

```
TFILES= $(shell cat files.list)
trial : $(TFILES)
    echo $<
```

but of course it wants each one to be a target. I want each one to be an object.

Comment: Why not just specify `$(TFILES)` as a target?  Begin a rule with `$(TFILES):` and specify dependencies (if any) and processing recipe.  Or have I missed the point?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear to me.  What do you mean by "I want each one to be an object", but not a target?  What output do you get from running this makefile, and what output were you hoping to get instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sufficiently new version of `make` (at least 4.1 I think) you can read files directly into a `make` variable without resorting to a shell call:

```
TFILES := $(file < files.list)
```

The syntax is a bit of an oddball among all `make` functions, as the `<` indeed determines the data direction, in this case "read". The opposite, `$(file > foo.txt,_whatever content you want_)` does writing. See also here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html

Not sure what you mean by "each one to be an object" though.

Comment: I don't see how this helps with the question asked.  There's no practical difference between this and the version in the question, except it doesn't invoke a shell.

Comment: @MadScientist absolutely, but it is still of better quality than the question. I propose to close it, also because the OP shows no effort to react or improve.